# Which one is wrong? Msdn or Headerfile

Tags: c#, c++, com, declaration

I am currently porting the `IAudioVolumeDuckNotification` to C#. But there is one problem with the declaration of the `OnVolumeUnduckNotification` method. 
Msdn tells me this: 
[image]

and my "audiopolicy.h" header file tells me this:
[image]

As you can see, in the msdn-version there is a second parameter. 
I am quite confused. Which one is the right one? Which one should I use and where can I report that mistake?

As requested the link to the msdn page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371012(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Rather than post screenshot images, it would be better to paste text inbetween appropriate tags and a link to the MSDN page where the information appears.

Comment: what do you mean with `text inbetween appropriate tags` @Brandin

Comment: Trust the header file. You're compiling the header files, not the docs.

Comment: @thefiloe Stackoverflow supports markdown tags to show which part of your text is source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SDK is always right, that's what you compile with.

MSDN tends to suffer from cut & paste bugs.  Hard to get fixed, the Windows group at Microsoft doesn't take feedback.  A liability of having a billion customers.

Comment: MSDN pages have a feedback link where you can leave a comment. Whether someone reads it is another thing, but saying that they don't accept feedback is not right

Comment: Why didn't you use it?